# Ubuntu 16.04 - Oracle 11g startup issue

Tags: sql, oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g, ubuntu-16.04

Hy, I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the database server is starting automatically when machine is opened even I have set to don't.
When I was prompted if I want to run Oracle on startup I taped 'no'.
The configuration from /etc/default/oracle-xe is:

```
#This is a configuration file for automatic starting of the Oracle
#Database and listener at system startup.It is generated By running
#'/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure'.Please use that method to modify this 
#file

# ORACLE_DBENABLED:'true' means to load the Database at system boot.
ORACLE_DBENABLED=false

# LISTENER_PORT: Database listener
LISTENER_PORT=1521

# HTTP_PORT : HTTP port for Oracle Application Express
HTTP_PORT=8090

# Configuration : Check whether configure has been done or not
CONFIGURE_RUN=true
```

The configuration from /etc/oratab is:

```
XE:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe:N
```

Even 'ORACLE_DBENABLED=false' the Oracle server is starting with operation system.
I can stop it manually, but it is frustrating and if I'm not stopping them, I have to wait 30-40 sec to shut down my computer (even I have ssd, and normally I stay 2, max 3 sec).

May someone can save me from this hell? :D

PS: On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS it was working well with same procedure to install.

Comment: That is strange, the :N in the oratab normally stops the oracle script from starting.Anyway, you can just delete `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe` (or `systemctl disable oracle.xe.service` I think).

Comment: Thaks, I used the disable method and it's very good.

Comment: Ok @doro, I made a answer out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the startup script is starting the database instance (or maybe it is only starting lisener and OEM console but not the instance?), since you have a `:N` marker in the `oratab`.

However in all cases you might be able to simply delete the init script `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe` or disable it in systemd: `systemctl disable oracle-xe.service`.